# Order of dropout and activation in 1D convolutional networks

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, lstm, dropout

I have a simple cnn-lstm network. There are two 1D convolutional layers after the input layer. Every 1D convolutional layer is followed by a dropout. What I observe is that when I have conv1D -> dropout -> activation, I get minimally better results (about 1%) compared with conv1D -> activation -> dropout (I use Relu as the activation function). I tried to find an example or some explanation of why this is the case, but couldn't find anything useful.
Can you think of any reason why it works this way?